# Issues while upgrading jquery from 1.2.7 to 1.9.1

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm in the process of upgrading an old codebase containing jquery v1.2.7 to the v1.2.9. The corresponding UI upgrade is from v.1.6b to v1.9.2 (1.10 doesn't work with IE6). There are a bunch of ui plugins that are atleast 6 yrs old, and most of their authors no longer actively support them.

I took a layered approach of performing this. I first upgraded all the core files (jquery, jqueryUI), then upgraded inhouse js code (attr, $.browser) and such. Then I monkey-patched some of the plugins that had attr and browser. I've managed to work through all the bugs and errors so far. I now have a "clean" build, with a lot of the ajax functionality working as well.

BUT, I'm facing a pretty sticky issue with the facebox.js (yup THAT relic) plugin. I don't see any errors (js, network, or others) in the debuggers (IE8,FB,Chrome), but the facebox dialog displays incorrectly. It still displays the content inside it, but it is transparent and the background and edges do no show. I checked all my css as well as validated using w3c validator. Due to an NDA, I can't post the markup here. I realize that without the markup, even the considerable expertise here might not be able to give a complete solution. Could someone atleast give me some pointers on what I could be overlooking, or things to look for? TIA

eastwood

Comment: What is your rationale for upgrading?

Comment: Have you try to migrate plugin using jquery migrate? http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/

Comment: Hi, that was a decision that was made above my paygrade, I was tasked with doing it. I did try using the migrate plugin, but without success. Also, the migrate plugin (as I read on one of the threads here) is only helpful if migrating from 1.6 and up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, without markup it's difficult to figure out what's going on there, and my answer might be really stupid - but since you don't get any errors in the debug consoles and the box is transparent - is it possible that the images are missing/incorrectly referenced in the CSS?

Not sure how this old facebook.js plugin works, but I've seen one some time ago that used images for backwards compatibility with IE6 (for alpha transparency/rounded borders) - but not always. I think for modern browsers it drew that stuff itself. (pretty much like Facebook did it itself on its site)

So perhaps the error is related to JavaScript expecting images/etc. to be handled by CSS, but the CSS uses an only-IE6-hack?

Comment: Hi Sebastien, I was getting a missing image error earlier. I identified via FB Network tab and fixed it. And yes, the facebox plugin does use images, and I've checked several times to make sure all the images are where they're supposed to be. The same plugin with the same css and same images works fine with jq 1.2.7. It's only when jq 1.9.1 is used, it doesn't. Your last point is interesting - seems like a lead worth following up on. I'll do just that and report back. appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Update: Boy, shore glad I checked up on that lead - the "good" build (with jq1.2.7) loads a gif image under the facebox folder. After doing the switcharoo with the "bad" build (with jq1.9.1), FB's Net console does NOT show the url to the aforementioned image file! This is a good start, hopefully this is the issue and can be nailed down. Thanks again for pointing me in this direction.

Comment: That turned out to be not the issue but, I see something that 'might' be of interest: the facebox is being loaded inside an iframe, through another old plugin[sigh] called bgiframe, like so:      //livequery is another plugin              jQuery('#facebox').livequery(function(){                jQuery('#facebox .popup').bgiframe();}); //followed by other ui widgets and such..

Comment: Baby-steps, but progress nonetheless! Upon doing an "inspect" in firebug, the css for the incorrect display is missing certain info, compared to the same css for the correctly displaying box. Will follow this to see if this is the cause of all this.

Comment: Well whadya know, the issue was that I'd used an upgraded version of the plugin that broke things. I reverted back to the older plugin version and voila, it works fine. Thanks to Sebastien and Lee for their comments!

reastwood

Comment: Glad I could help. Issues like that sometimes need a totally different approach :)